# Слушатель NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-view

Всем доброго дня!

Необходимо из фрагмента узнать, что был нажат 'Гамбургер' NavigationView.

Сам 'Гамбургер' я заменил стрелкой Вверх, и смогу сделать возврат назад, но никак не пойму как поймать нажатие.

В данный момент фрагмент выглядит так:

```
public class Photo extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnBackPressedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    // кнопка Вверх
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile activity = (Profile) getActivity();
        if (activity != null) activity.showUpButton();
    }

    // кнопка возврата назад
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Profile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через Callback.
В в основной activity создаешь интерфейс

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks;
 public interface Callbacks {
    void clickGamburger();
        }
```

В фрагменте наследуешь интерфейс implements YoursActiviry.Callbacks
Переопределяешь метод. В этом методе у тебя будет передаваться информация от activity в  fragment.

На следующем шаге необходимо подключить Collback к fragment.

```
Fragment fragment = new Photo();
mCallbacks = (Photo) fragment;
```

Теперь можешь в нужном месте activity вызывать

```
   mCallbacks.clickGamburger();
```

Oн автоматически запустит clickGamburger в твоем фрагменте.

Comment: Вызвать возврат в Активити из фрагмента я могу, лучше подскажите как определить нажатие на главную кнопку NavigationView?

Comment: Надо повесить слушатель callback в меню

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        mCallbacks.clickGamburger();.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
А в фрагменте уже реализовать переопределение метода интерфейса

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте реализовать `onOptionsItemSelected`, и в нем же получите ссылку на стрелку вверх.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // Действия для кнопки вверх.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Данный метод у меня есть в Активити с NavigationView, но он не вызывается. Если добавить его в фрагмент он так же молчит.